# Drawing lines in canvas using accelerometer sensor data in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, wpf-controls, accelerometer

I am drawing on canvas based on device movement, I want to draw different characters in canvas based on mobile movement.

Currently its working, but I want to find time difference and i want to detect pause, pause means when user is not trying to draw and user is not moving mobile phone, so that Application ca assume that now user want to draw next character.

How to find pause in accelerometer values. Any logic? Also tell me how i can smooth accelerometer values, so that user can draw lines without noise.

Comment: [Weighted Moving Average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Weighted_moving_average) should help you deal with noise data.

Comment: But how to define weight values , i am treating all values as equal. Also tell me i have accelerometer values in 3 AXIS but drawing line in 2D (x and y) how to decide 2D points based on 3D to make lines more effiecient.

Comment: Just decide how many of the previous points you want to use.Add those up, f.ex. if 5 last ones, then 5+4+3+2+1 = 15. Now you weight the 5. last point using 1/15, the 4. last 2/15 etc. until they all sum up to the value for current position, continue with the next. Same for each axis. What language do you use (VB.net/C#..)?

Comment: I gave an answer dwelling more into moving avg. It's perhaps not entirely what you ask for - considered it as an addendum if not. The code is in JS, it should be easy to convert to VB/C#/C++ etc. if you use one of those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot help with the accelerator part, but for the noise in the data, here is one approach using **[Weighted Moving Average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Weighted_moving_average)**.

The basics are simple:

- Find out how many points before current you want to use for smoothing
- Calculate a weight based on length, f.ex. if length is 5 then the weight = 1+2+3+4+5 = 15
- Iterate each data point starting from length of weight (you can start at 1 and cut the weighting short - below I'll demo the latter approach)
- For point current - 5 multiply with 1/15, for current - 4 multiply with 2/15 and so forth. The sum is stored as value for this point, repeat for the next value points

## Live demo

Below is a demo (enter full page to see all graphics). I wrote it in JavaScript so it could be shown live here in the answer. I think you should have little problem converting it into the language you're using (which is not stated).

Move the slider to increase number of points to weight. You can run the data through several passes to smooth even more. The original data is a sinus curve with noise jitter. With many points you can see the curve smooths to replicate this. Just using 9-10 points length over 2 passes will give a good result with very little time delay:

```js
var ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d"),
    rng = document.querySelector("input"),
    val = document.querySelector("span"),
    data = [], scale = 30;

// generate sinus wave with noise jitters
for(var i = 0; i < ctx.canvas.width; i += 2)
    data.push(Math.sin(i*0.1) * Math.random() + Math.random())

// draw initial smoothed curve (length=1, no smoothing)
drawWMA();

// calculate moving average
function drawWMA() {
    var len = +rng.value,        // get smoothing length (number of previous points)
        dataa = [], datab = [],  // pass A and B arrays
        weight = 0;              // calc weight based on length
  
  val.innerHTML = len;
  
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
  ctx.beginPath();
  
  // calc weight
  for(var i = 1; i <= len; i++) weight += i;  // add range together [1, length]
  
  // plot original data at top of canvas
  plot(data, 30);

  // PASS 1: Calc new smoothed array
  dataa = calcWMA(data, len, weight);
  
  // plot smoothed curve
  ctx.fillText("FIRST PASS:", 0, 100);
  plot(dataa, 120);
    
  // PASS 2 (optional)
  datab = calcWMA(dataa, len, weight);
  ctx.fillText("SECOND PASS:", 0, 190);
  plot(datab, 210);
  
  ctx.stroke();  // render plots
}

function calcWMA(data, len, weight) {
  var i, t, datao = [];
  
  // calc new smoothed array 
  for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {       // iterate from length to end of data
    var v = 0;                             // calc average value for this position
    for(t = 0; t < len; t++) {             // [1, len]
      if (i-t >= 0)
        v += data[i-t] * ((t+1) / weight); // weight previous values based on -delta
    }
    datao.push(v);                         // store new value
  }
  return datao
}

function plot(data, y) {
  ctx.moveTo(0, y + data[0]*scale);
  for(i = 1; i < data.length; i++) ctx.lineTo(i * 2, y + data[i]*scale);
}

rng.onchange = rng.oninput = drawWMA;
```

```html
<label>Points to consider: <input type="range" min=1 max=50 value=1></label><span>1</span><br>
<canvas width=600 height=300></canvas>
```

A different approach would be to use a [Savitzky–Golay filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savitzky%E2%80%93Golay_filter) which gives a similar result, but not "sacrifice" any points at the end (moving average will push forward or crop at the end).