# Is there a way to reliably detect when an audio recording has too much background noise?

Tags: audio, signal-processing, web-audio-api

For my work we do online testing for English language learners. Part of that involves doing speech audio recordings of the students. We do this through the MediaRecorder js API for Firefox and Chrome. This works well as an efficient solution to test a large number of students quickly, but we find that the testing environment is sometimes too noisy for the graders to evaluate the students.

We'd like to be able to automatically detect if the background noise level is too great and alert the student if it is, but I'm doubtful as to how feasible this is. Part of the problem is that most of the background noise typically isn't what we'd think of as white noise, but is instead produced by other human voices of other test takers. As such, I'm unsure if typical SNR algorithms could distinguish between a noisy environment and a normal response. I just wanted to ask around to see if there's any way to get some automated measurement that would allow us to identify likely candidates for unintelligible recordings due to loud background noise. Like I said, I'm doubtful that there's an easy solution, but I figured I'd ask just in case.

Answer (score 2):

Put a countdown on-screen at the start of your test:  "Starting test in 3... 2... 1...", and expect the student to be quiet for a couple seconds during the countdown.

If the microphone isn't sufficiently quiet for at least 2 seconds, then warn about the noise and give a "continue anyway/try again/quit choice"  If the student was talking during the countdown, they'll figure out that they were the noise and try again without talking.

Answer (score 1):

Just some thoughts -

You could measure the average sound level over time to see if it is more or less constant or closer to a natural variable level (using [weighted moving average](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30095893/1693593) and RMS is possibly a good starting point without testing). Work out a threshold where it's likely that the more or less constant level is caused by background sound.

Other than that it is close to "impossible" to separate sounds this way. White-noise, hissing and humming sure, even fingerprinting noise to run through a noise filter (but probably to intense for real-time use in a browser *and* you would need something to produce the fingerprint from).

But when the "noise" is other human voices it will become extremely difficult as the sounds become too similar. Even advanced software such as iZotope RX cannot do this even when specifically defining the characteristics of what you want to have removed. The complexity would in any case probably require too much of a poor browser.

Physical solutions: A more directional microphone could deal with some of this but would also require more attention by the user as to correct placement. A small [portable "sound booth"](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Essentials-Recording-Portable-Project-Studios/dp/B0045CXIUI/278-7614686-2841767?ie=UTF8&SubscriptionId=AKIAILSHYYTFIVPWUY6Q&camp=2025&creative=165953&creativeASIN=B0045CXIUI&linkCode=xm2&tag=duckduckgo-ffnt-uk-21) (link meant as an example) to take some noise away from the sides and behind, if possible to setup at location.

My 2 cents..